# Are there any vector subspaces which can be expressed through a system of nonlinear equations?

Tags: linear-algebra

My textbook says that a subset of a $K^n$ vector space is a linear subspace if and only if it can be expressed through a system of homogeneous linear equations. I tried to find a counterexample.

By definition, said $V$ a vector space over a field $K$

A nonempty subset $U$ of $V$ is a subspace of $V$ if and only if

1. if $u_1, u_2 \in U$ then $u_1+u_2 \in U$;
2. if $a\in K$ and $u \in U$ then $au \in U$.

now assume we have some field, again call it $K$, thus $K^n$ is a vector space over itself given the following operations:

$$(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)+(y_1,y_2,\dots,y_n)$$
$$a(x_1,x_2,\dots,x_n)$$

In such a circumstance is it possible to find a subset that can be expressed through a system of non-linear equations which also fulfill the conditions of the definition above?

For instance, I was thinking about the following example:

given the vector space $\mathbb Z_2^3$ and the subset of the former $$U=\{(x,y,z) \mid x-y+z^2=0 \pmod 2\}$$

so even though this subset is described by a nonlinear equation it does fulfill the two conditions above $(1,2)$ and by definition, $U$ should be a vector subspace. what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, here is an example. Consider the subset of $(x,y)$ of $\Bbb R^2$ satisfying the non-linear equation $x^2+y^2=0$. This is a subspace.

Comment: To produce a counterexample to the textbook's claim, you'd need to show that your subspace *can't* be expressed as the solution of a system of linear equations. Showing that it can be expressed with nonlinear equations isn't enough.

Comment: @Rushy Not in characteristic $2$: just in $\Bbb F_2$. In $\Bbb F_4$ you have $\alpha^2=\alpha+1$ for all $\alpha\notin\Bbb F_2$.

Comment: @Karl you are right, i misquoted the text without noticing, thank you, just edited